# SQL query for finding maximum amount month wise with the user

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I want to print maximum sum amount per month with the user who has done the maximum amount. My table structure is

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| customername | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| processed_at | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| amount       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and 
the query to print maximum sum month wise is

```
SELECT MAX(A.AMT), A.month
FROM ( SELECT customername,SUM(amount) AS AMT, EXTRACT( month from processed_at) as month
FROM payments
GROUP BY customername,month) AS A
GROUP BY  2;
```

this is giving the result

```
| MAX(A.AMT) | month |
+------------+-------+
|       1900 |     4 |
|       2400 |     3 |
```

is there a way in which customername can also be mapped to maximum amount?

Comment: You have mistakenly tagged two different DBMS: Oracle and MySQL. Which of the two are you using and which version exactly?

Comment: Either way, this is the most frequently asked question under these tags.

Comment: Updated it is MySQL

Comment: You want to display the maximum amount per month and per customer or just per month?

Anyway you could use a subquery to display max customer value from that month.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: I want to display maximum amount per month and using mysql 8.0.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        customername,
        SUM(amount) amt, 
        DATE_FORMAT(processed_at, '%Y-%m-01') yr_month,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(processed_at, '%Y-%m-01') ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) rn
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY customername, yr_month
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Note that this includes the month *and* year in the `GROUP BY` clause, in case your data spreads over more than 12 months.

In earlier versions, one option is to filter with a `HAVING` clause and a correlated aggregate query:

```
SELECT 
    customername,
    SUM(amount) amt, 
    DATE_FORMAT(processed_at, '%Y-%m-01') yr_month
FROM payments p
GROUP BY customername, yr_month
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT SUM(p1.amount)
    FROM payments p
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(p1.processed_at, '%Y-%m-01') = yr_month
    GROUP BY p1.customername
    ORDER BY SUM(p1.amount) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```